# MVC Route ignoring for angularjs directive templates

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, templates, angularjs-directive, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using angularjs + MVC.
I am creating some angularjs directives. I want to put templates inside the View folder.. I think is a cleaner solution than having another folder that contains the template. Following the structure of my solution, I think that is nothing special:

- Root

  - Areas
  - Scripts

    - Directives (here I have angular directives)
  - Views

    - Shared

      - Templates (here I have the templates of the directives)

Here an example of directive:

```
angular.module('qbDirectives', []).directive('qbPreloader', ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/Views/Shared/Templates/qbPreloader.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) { ... }
        ...
    };
}]);
```

As you can see, the template is an HTML file, not a CSHTML.. When I run my application I obtain this client error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:52746/Views/Shared/Templates/qbPreloader.html

The physical path is correct but the template is not found. I think the problem is that MVC can access the View folder just with routing, so MVC need a controller to load the resource.
I do not want to do a server side call to obtain the template so I am trying to ignore the route.
In my global.asax I wrote

```
routes.IgnoreRoute(
            "{*staticfile}",
            new { staticfile = @".*\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|js|css|htm|html|htc)$" }
        );
```

or

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Views/Shared/Templates/{file}.html");
```

Buth nothing works. I still have the same problem. 
How do I have to ignore the route correctly?

Thank you

Comment: If you put the templates into another folder, like Root/templates, do they load then? (just for testing purposes)

Comment: if I put the template outside a foolder that is not under rooting, everything works correctly